# How to choose which tools to download in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

For personal reasons, I have limited internet. :(, that is why I want to choose only the necessary tools to compile APKs, I only give it download, for example: `plarform-tools` and android studio shows me the complete list of what I am downloading:

Chosen option:

```
      platform-tools
```

What android studio wants to download:

```
    plarform-tools // I want to download.

    Android emulator // I do not want to download it,  because it is not necessary (since I have an android device) and it weighs a painful 300MGb.

    etc ... // All the other tools I need to compile APKs (I think), but not chosen either.
```

The problem is that I swear I must download the android emulator, how can I not download the android emulator or choose to download in android studio?

Comment: Do you have a traffic limit (? GB per month) or is it just the time you want to save? If it is the first be aware that for Android development the required tools to be downloaded is way longer. Android studio uses gradle and Android development plugin (each another few hundred MB), and then all the required Java libraries for compiling and gradle. Consider about at least another 1-2GB before your first project is built.

Comment: @Robert 0_0. Goodbye android . Not only is it a game, I have the java virtual machine (I have no problem with this) and with the compilation I imagine that it does not require that much (because I had a mobile app that compiled APKs and it weighed about 120MGB).

Comment: Games usually contain a lot of graphics, 3d models, audio, video... An 120MB Android game app is nothing unusual, and comparing it with the iOS eco system 120MB is small, an iOS app (not game) is typically 50-200MB large.

Comment: @Robert I dont understand, the App is a IDE and compiler of APKs no a game, but yes it runs on an android phone.